# javascript not loading in wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I originally posted this in the stackoverflow, but I believe it is better posted here as I am using wordpress and a wordpress function.  I am trying to add the jquery cycle plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to my wordpress site, so I enqueued it in my functions.php, and then added a script right before the /body tag.  When I load the page, I get the error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function.  When I open the source file, the cycle plugin script is also not there.  I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

To break down what I did, I downloaded the jquery.cycle.all.js file and put in in my child theme (lets call it TestChild) in the directory like so TestChild/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js.  I then declared the wp_enqueue_script function in my functions.php.  I then added the script before my /body tag. I would appreciate any help as this has been causing me hours of frustration.

This is my code:

```
    function theme_add_cycle_slide (){
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script('cycleall', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js', array ('jquery'), null, true);
    }
    add_action ('wp_enqueue_script', 'theme_add_cycle_slide' );

    <div id="slideshow">
      <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:red;"></div>
      <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:blue;"></div>
      <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:green;"></div>
      <div style="width:250px; height:150px; background:yellow;"></div>
        <div id="prev" style="float:left;">PREV</div>
        <div id="next" style="float:right;">NEXT</div>
    </div>

     <script language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:    'fade',
        pause:  1
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed one thing finally.  For the function, in add _action it should be 'wp_enqueue_scripts' not 'wp_enqueue_script'.  Now I have another error.  [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a simple misspelling.

The add_action should be

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_cycle_slide' );

I wrote 'script'

Answer (score 0):

Try This one :

```
  wp_register_script('cycleall', plugins_url('/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('cycleall');
```

change script to scripts in `add_action()` should be

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_cycle_slide' );
```

Comment: nope get_template_directory_uri()  will give the path for parent theme not the child

Comment: yeah you are right